# Bootstrap columns and justify-content-end

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm having difficulty getting my columns to spread out.

According to the docs (https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/layout/columns/#horizontal-alignment), `justify-content-between` should be what I need.

But I end up with my columns in their default position, not pushed outwards.

Basic code example:

https://codepen.io/6a0a49af-a3f9-4e78-8ccf-91d8d1b1f102/pen/QWKYJqM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have changed your code a little to get the desired effect.

On `<div class="row">` i removed some unneeded styles.
and on the `<div class="col">` i changed it to col-4 to set the width.
Since bootstrap works in a frame of 12. 4 + 4 leaves 4 short so thats the space thats being filled with `justify-content-between`.
I also deleted your css since it was not needed.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
<body class="d-flex flex-column min-vh-100">
  <!-- -->
  <nav class="navbar navbar-light navbar-expand-md bg-light">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
        <img src="img/logo.svg" alt="">
      </a>
      <!-- -->
      <div class="navbar-nav d-none d-md-flex">
        <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Home</a>
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">A</a>
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">B</a>
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">C</a>
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">D</a>
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">E</a>
      </div>
      <!-- -->
      <span>
        <a href="https://twitter.com/" rel="nofollow noopener noreferrer"><i
            class="fab fa-twitter mx-2 gstwitterblue"></i></a>
        <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/"
          rel="nofollow noopener noreferrer"><i class="fab fa-linkedin mx-2 gslinkedinblue"></i></a>
      </span>
    </div>
  </nav>
  <main class="flex-fill">
     <div class="container d-none d-md-flex flex-md-row">
      <div class="row justify-content-between">
        <div class="col-4">
          <div class="card">
            <div class="ratio ratio-16x9">
              <iframe src="https://www.youtube-nocookie.com/embed/wm48_VrbB4Q?rel=0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
            </div>
            <div class="card-body">
              <p class="card-text">

               Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam efficitur orci malesuada sem lacinia, vitae tempor tellus auctor. Sed elementum iaculis quam ac consectetur. Nam ac laoreet est, ut placerat arcu. Ut viverra, quam vitae gravida ornare, arcu felis elementum elit, a pulvinar lacus augue ac nisl. Nunc tincidunt ultricies luctus. Donec et congue ex. Curabitur lacinia scelerisque imperdiet. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Aenean ultricies, mauris at ultricies dapibus, urna nisl ullamcorper libero, ac dictum ex neque sed ante. Pellentesque luctus nibh libero, consequat vulputate eros porttitor vitae.</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      <div class="col-4">
        <div class="card gscustomwidth">
          <div class="ratio ratio-16x9">
            <iframe src="https://www.youtube-nocookie.com/embed/wm48_VrbB4Q?rel=0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
          </div>
          <div class="card-body">
            <p class="card-text">

            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam efficitur orci malesuada sem lacinia, vitae tempor tellus auctor. Sed elementum iaculis quam ac consectetur. Nam ac laoreet est, ut placerat arcu. Ut viverra, quam vitae gravida ornare, arcu felis elementum elit, a pulvinar lacus augue ac nisl. Nunc tincidunt ultricies luctus. Donec et congue ex. Curabitur lacinia scelerisque imperdiet. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Aenean ultricies, mauris at ultricies dapibus, urna nisl ullamcorper libero, ac dictum ex neque sed ante. Pellentesque luctus nibh libero, consequat vulputate eros porttitor vitae. </p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
    </main>
  <!-- Standard Footer -->
  <footer class="bg-light py-3 d-none d-md-flex">
    <div class="container d-flex justify-content-between">
      <span class="text-dark fw-lighter">Copyright © 2020 Foobar Ltd. All rights reserved.</span>
      <span class="text-dark fw-lighter"><a href="#" class="text-reset text-decoration-none">Legal
          Information</a></span>
    </div>
  </footer>
  </body>
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason what you want doesn't happen is because you're not giving the `row` div a full width. From your code, add `w-100` to the following div:

```html
<div class="row row-cols-1 row-cols-md-2 justify-content-between">
```